# What exactly is/means "System.IO.Stream+NullStream"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I am currently experimenting to find the proper way of creating an HTTP context for unit testing purposes. While examining the stream types created, I was surprised that the following returns a type of `System.IO.Stream+NullStream`.

```
var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

var requestBodyType = context.Request.Body.GetType().FullName; 
var responseBodyType = context.Response.Body.GetType().FullName;
```

If the test case requires it, I'd simply replace the stream with a `MemoryStream` and then act upon it accordingly.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var context = new DefaultHttpContext(); 
context.Response.Body = memoryStream;
```

So far so good. But what *exactly* is `System.IO.Stream+NullStream`? I would have expected to find a type of `NullStream` in the documentation, but couldn't find such a thing.

Comment: It's an [internal type](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stream.cs,05639b04df9c5d6a). It sub-classes `Stream`, and is exposed as [`Stream.Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.null?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [internal type](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stream.cs,05639b04df9c5d6a).

It sub-classes `Stream`, and is exposed as [`Stream.Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.null?view=net-6.0).

As you can see from the implementation, it just throws away any data written to it, and doesn't return any data if asked.

Answer (score 3):

The hierarchy for `System.IO.Stream+NullStream` looks like this

```
public abstract class Stream {

    private sealed class NullStream {
    
    }
    
}
```

The + means it's a nested child class of Stream